# Read data from binary file with condition

Tags: c, conditional-statements, binaryfiles

I'm trying to read data from binary file to linked list, but I can't understand how to add condition and read only special entries. For example, how to read cars with place = street?

Struct:

```
typedef struct S_RacingCar {

    char name[12];
    char place[12];
    int speed;
    struct S_RacingCar *next;
    struct S_RacingCar *previous;

} RacingCar;
```

Reading from file:

```
RacingCar *ReadNextFromFile(RacingCar *start, FILE *pFile) {
    size_t returnValue;
    if(start == NULL) {
        start = malloc(sizeof(RacingCar));
        returnValue = fread(start, sizeof(RacingCar), 1, pFile);
        start->next = NULL;
        start->previous = NULL;
    } else {
        RacingCar *indexCar = start;
        RacingCar *newCar = malloc(sizeof(RacingCar));
        while(indexCar->next != NULL) {
            indexCar = indexCar->next;
        }
        returnValue = fread(newCar, sizeof(RacingCar), 1, pFile);
        indexCar->next = newCar;
        newCar->next = NULL;
        newCar->previous = indexCar;
    }
    return start;
}

RacingCar *ReadListIn(RacingCar *start) {

    FILE *pFile;
    pFile = fopen("myList.bin", "rb");
    if(pFile != NULL) {

        CleanUp(start);
        start = NULL;

        fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
        long fileSize = ftell(pFile);
        rewind(pFile);

        int numEntries = (int)(fileSize / (sizeof(RacingCar)));
        printf("numEntries:%d\n",numEntries);

        int loop = 0;
        for(loop = 0; loop < numEntries; ++loop) {
            fseek(pFile, (sizeof(RacingCar) * loop), SEEK_SET);
            start = ReadNextFromFile(start, pFile);
        }
    }  else {
        printf("FILE OPEN ERROR FOR READ\n");
    }

    return start;

}
```

Comment: TL;DR! Please narrow down the code to the parts where you have your problem. Or even better, try to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: I tried to add the condition in while loop (ReadNextFromFile), but what should I do with returnValue.

Comment: If you enable all the warnings when compiling (for gcc, at least '-Wall -Wextra -pedantic')  then you would see the warning from function: 'ReadNextFromFile()' about the variable: 'returnValue'  that gets set, in two different places in the function, from results of a call to fread(), but never used.   Returned values from system functions should be checked for error conditions (and any errors fixed).

Comment: No result if... read all records
while(indexCar->next != NULL) {
        if (strcmp(indexCar->place,"male") == 0) {
            returnValue = fread(newCar, sizeof(RacingCar), 1, pFile);
            indexCar = indexCar->next;}
  }

Comment: when calling malloc() (and family of functions) always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful

Comment: @user3629249 could you post your code please

Comment: when calling the fseek() system function, the returned value needs to be checked (==0) to assure the operation was successful

Comment: the line: printf("FILE OPEN ERROR\n"); does not help the user to fix the problem.  suggest using 'perror()'  as that will also output the OS message for the current value of errno.

Comment: when calling the system function: sscanf(): 1) always check the returned value (not the parameter value) to assure the operation was successful.  2) place a length modifier on the %s format parameter so the input buffer is not overrun, thereby eliminating the chance of undefined behavior, which could lead to a seg fault event.

Comment: the main() function has a number of recognized possible user input values, but does not list those values to the user.  for robustness, suggest 1) output a 'menu' at the top of the loop 2) have the user just enter a single digit, 3) use that digit to drive a switch statement

Comment: when an error occurs, it is a bad idea to continue execution.  much better to cleanup and memory allocations, close any open files, the call: 'exit( EXIT_FAILURE );'

Comment: in function: ReadListIn(): 1) there is no need to determine the size of the file  2) there is no need to call fseek() before each call to ReadNextFromFile()  3) the call to ReadListIn(), in main(),  results in the list head pointer (start) pointing to the last entry in the linked list, rather than the first entry.

Comment: @user3629249 it is a really cool!

Answer (score 2):

You would want to add the condition prior to modifying the list. For example,

```
RacingCar temp;
returnValue = fread(&temp, sizeof temp, 1, pFile);
if (returnValue != 1) {
    if (ferror(pFile)) {
        puts("Error reading from file");
    }
    return start;
}

if (strncmp(temp.place, "street", sizeof temp.place)) {
    return start;
}
```

Once these two conditions have passed we can guarantee we'll be using some memory, so we can allocate some dynamic memory to store the object and add the car into the list:

```
RacingCar *newCar = malloc(sizeof *newCar);
if (newCar == NULL) {
    puts("Error allocating car");
    return start;
}


*newCar = temp;
newCar->next = NULL;
newCar->previous = indexCar;

indexCar->next = newCar;
```

Comment: Thank you (+1), but... Are you test your code? "street", not street, if I not mistaken, and I don't clearly understand how to modify ReadListIn. Could you post your code.

Comment: the posted suggestion is correct, as the code is not looking for the literal 'street' but rather, looking for a match between the target car usage indicator and the car usage indicator in the struct RacingCar field.   However, no such field currently exists, so that field (and the input statement to acquire that field from the user) needs to be added to the code.

Comment: Indeed. The field doesn't exist, so I couldn't possibly know how to compare it, aside from the pseudocodeish suggestion you gave in the question "For example, how to read cars with place = street". It should go without saying, if that field were to denote a fixed-width string, you'd want to use `strncmp` to compare rather than `!=`...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour, I am very sorry! Could add some more details please.

Comment: regarding this line: 'if (temp.place != street) {'  'place is a multi character field.  need to use something like: strcmp() to make the comparison

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour It isn't work... New function http://pastebin.com/shYF7XXG not work. Full code http://pastebin.com/VThKfRsj Please help to run

Comment: @huxahetu Ooops! My bad... I had a baby screaming in my ear. I've changed `returnValue = fread(start, sizeof temp, 1, pFile);` to `returnValue = fread(&temp, sizeof temp, 1, pFile);`. You'll probably want to modify the `if` branch before the `else` branch, too...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour thank you! Now works, but a little bit strange. Reading all entries, but when I print it - works fine o_0 What happend?

Comment: Full code with problem: http://pastebin.com/kupfb2JQ Test:add \Enter
ff male 1\Enter
add \Enter
ss another 2\Enter
add \Enter
tt male 3\Enter
write\Enter
Then input read and print

Comment: -sigh-... You know, code is a lot like a recipe: If you start changing the orders of things, you might introduce all kinds of subtle problems that you don't yet understand. I suggest learning how to use valgrind, sooner rather than later...

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour thank you for you reply. I'll try valgrind! Thank you! Last question: is all ok with realization of you solution: http://pastebin.com/KXNMGEgc (like using temp variable etc)

Answer (score 2):

the following code, of the ReadNextFromFile() has some/a few of the problems fixed,  however there are plenty more, which I have not fixed.

I have not added to code to cleanup all the allocated memory when an error occurs.

I have not added any checking to differentiate between EOF and a I/O error.

```
a struct should not be typedef'd.  There are several reasons why.
among those reasons are:
1) typedef'ing a struct clutters the code
2) typedef'ing a struct leads to mis-understandings, especially for typedef'd pointers
3) typedef'ing a struct clutters the compiler namespace


struct RacingCar
{
    char name[12];
    int speed;
    struct RacingCar *next;
    struct RacingCar *previous;
};

'magic' numbers should not be used.
They greatly reduce the understandability of the code, 
and they make for maintenance nightmares.
use a #define, with a meaningful name
then use that name through out the code

When calling 'fgets()' the full length of the 
input buffer should be used.
fgets() will properly stop before overflowing the input buffer

#define MAX_USER_INPUT_LENGTH (16)



struct RacingCar *ReadNextFromFile( struct RacingCar *start, FILE *pFile)
{
    if( NULL == start )
    {
        if( NULL == (start = malloc(sizeof( struct RacingCar))
        { // then malloc failed
            perror( "malloc for struct RacingCar failed" );
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        if( 1 != fread(start, sizeof(struct RacingCar), 1, pFile)
        { // then fread failed
            perror( "fread for struct RacingCar, from file, failed");
            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, fread successful


        start->next = NULL;
        start->previous = NULL;
    }

    else
    {
        struct RacingCar *indexCar = start;
        struct RacingCar *newCar = NULL;


        if ( NULL == (newCar = malloc(sizeof( struct RacingCar )) ) )
        {// then, malloc failed
            perror( "malloc for new car failed" );

            exit( EXIT_FAILURE );
        }

        // implied else, malloc successful

        while(indexCar->next != NULL)
        {
            indexCar = indexCar->next;
        }

        if( 1 != fread( newCar, sizeof(struct RacingCar), 1, pFile)
        { // then fread failed
            perror( "fread for struct RacingCar, from file, failed" );

            start = NULL;
        }

        // implied else, fread successful

        indexCar->next = newCar;
        newCar->next = NULL;
        newCar->previous = indexCar;
    }
    return start;
} // end function: ReadNextFromFile
```

Comment: Thank you! But where I can add the check for place == street?

Comment: In the 'Insert()' function, 1) there needs to be a prompt to tell the user what to enter (an car name) and the trailing newline '\n' needs to be removed from the input before making any string comparisons. 2) the function will fail if there is not a struct RacingCar in the linked list that already contains the same name

Comment: `struct RacingCar *newCar NULL;`?

Comment: in Function: WriteListToFile(), 1) there is no need to call fseek to find the end of the file.  just use "ab" instead of "wb" when opening the file.  2) the "wb" will already have trimmed the file to zero length and each call to fwrite() will have advanced the file position pointer.  3) the posted code removed the struct RacingCar from the linked list, but fails to call free().  The result is a memory leak.

Comment: @undefinedbehaviour,  Thanks, a keypunch error, I'll edit to fix.

Comment: @user3629249 please help me to run this code... Full code: http://pastebin.com/VThKfRsj New function http://pastebin.com/shYF7XXG

Comment: Full code with problem: pastebin.com/kupfb2JQ Test:add \Enter ff male 1\Enter add \Enter ss another 2\Enter add \Enter tt male 3\Enter write\Enter Then input read and print